# "A word as Verb + ing" vs "that word as a Noun"

Tags: verbs, gerunds, nouns, prepositional-phrases

For a word like "Mix", we can know it either a noun or a verb. So my question is:
If I want to choose a title for my book, **The Art of Mixing** is the same as **The Art of Mix**? Are both of them OK? Or is the latter wrong? I know the first one is OK, but how about the second one?

Comment: _Mixing_ describes the process, which may well involve artistry. A _mix_ is some combination, and it makes no sense to refer to 'the art of [a] mix'.

Comment: It could also be, **The Art of The Mix**...  That to me would be specific to the subject, for example a book about  what a deejay does in a popular club.

Answer (score 1):

"mixing" a gerund, or a verbal noun means "an act" which may be done skillfully, or even artfully.

"a mix" is a combination of two or more substances.

I guess the implied context here is "mixing music tracks together" as this provided the best opportunity for "art". In this context, "a mix" is the result of "mixing". The art is in the mixing, so you would normally say "The art of mixing".

By comparison, "a cake" is the result of "baking".  It makes more sense to say "The art of baking" than "the art of cake".

This doesn't mean "The art of mix" is wrong. But normally it is not the meaning that you want to give.

Answer (score -1):

Reference [Gerunds](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerund.htm)

> The Art of Mixing is the same as The Art of Mix?

No. "The Art of Mixing" is correct, "The Art of Mix" is not.

This is because of the use of the verb "to mix".  In the first instant, the art of mixing, "mixing" is actually a gerund, a verb form which functions as a noun. The word "mixing" can replace a noun in a sentence, for example:

- I like apples
- I like cats
- I like mixing.

In this case, I am not doing mixing, I am not performing the action of mixing, I am using "mixing" as a thing, a hobby that I can perform an action on.  In this context the word mixing is a **gerund**.  Not to be confused with the "present participle" of "I am mixing" which is used as a verb to suggest that I am performing the action of mixing.

In the second case, "The Art of Mix", the structure "mix" is a verb.  I mix, she mixes, they mix, we mix.  It doesn't make sense to use the verb to mix as a noun.  A gerund always ends with -ing.  In order to make this make sense it would have to read something like "The art of how I mix batter" or "The art of how we mix paint".  If you are going to use "mix" it must be used as a verb, however if you use "mixing" you can used it as a noun (gerund)

Comment: Also " we can know it either a noun or a verb" would sound better as " we know it can be used as either a noun or a verb".  'we can' is never used with know, either "we can use" to mean we are able to use it, or "we know" to mean that we are aware of.

Comment: Actually mix is also a noun, but I agree that The Art of Mix wouldn't make sense. You could say The Art of the Mix or The Art of Mixes.